# Interrupts in raspberry pi using python 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

In my project I'm using a raspberry pi (with python 3). I'm trying to introduce an interrupt with a press button that I can stop or pause the main function and process another function and after finishing it the main should be released. I'm using this :

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)
```

But I'm facing a problem, when the push button is pressed the "main" and "my_callback" are executing together !!

Then I tried to work on threads, making the main and my_callback as threads, but the same result.

Could anyone help me please.
Here is my code.

```
import os
import MySQLdb
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GreenRight = 3
RedRight = 5
GreenUp = 11
RedUp = 13
PushButton = 15
YellowRight = 40

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(GreenRight, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RedRight, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GreenUp, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RedUp, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(YellowRight, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(PushButton, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down= GPIO.PUD_UP)


db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "***.***.*.***", port=3306, user = "****", passwd = "***", db = "mydb")
cur = db.cursor()

lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23],numbering_mode=GPIO.BOARD)
lcd.clear()

def TurnOnGreenHorizental(time):

    sql1 = "UPDATE `test` SET `Green Light For Horizental`='ON' WHERE `Street`='StreetRight'"
    cur.execute(sql1)
    sql2 = "UPDATE `test` SET `Red Light For Horizental`='OFF' WHERE `Street`='StreetLeft'"
    cur.execute(sql1)

    i=time
    GPIO.output(GreenRight, True)
    GPIO.output(RedRight, False)
    GPIO.output(GreenUp, False)
    GPIO.output(RedUp, True)
    GPIO.output(YellowRight, False)

    while i > 0:
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.write_string("HS Green Lights ON for "+str(i)+ " s")
        sleep(1)
        i=i-1

    lcd.clear()
    GPIO.output(GreenRight, False)
    GPIO.output(RedRight, False)    
    GPIO.output(RedUp, False)
    GPIO.output(GreenUp, False)
    GPIO.output(YellowRight, False)
    sleep(4)

def TurnOnVertical(time):


    sql1 = "UPDATE `test` SET `Green Light For Horizental`='OFF' WHERE `Street`='StreetRight'"
    cur.execute(sql1)
    sql2 = "UPDATE `test` SET `Red Light For Horizental`='ON' WHERE `Street`='StreetLeft'"
    cur.execute(sql1)

    i = time
    GPIO.output(GreenRight, True)
    GPIO.output(RedRight, False)
    GPIO.output(GreenUp, False)
    GPIO.output(RedUp, True)
    GPIO.output(YellowRight, False)

    while i > 0:
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.write_string("HS Green Lights ON for "+str(i)+ " s")
        sleep(1)
        i=i-1

    lcd.clear()
    GPIO.output(GreenRight, False)
    GPIO.output(RedRight, False)    
    GPIO.output(RedUp, False)
    GPIO.output(GreenUp, False)
    GPIO.output(YellowRight, False)
    sleep(4)


def my_callback(channel):    

    c=12
    print("button is pressed" )
    GPIO.output(YellowRight, True)
    GPIO.output(GreenUp,False)
    GPIO.output(RedUp,False)
    GPIO.output(RedRight,False)
    GPIO.output(GreenRight,False)

    while c >0:
       lcd.clear()
       lcd.write_string("Passenger light is ON  for "+str(c)+ " s")
       sleep(1)
       c=c-1

QUERY= "SELECT `Action` FROM `test`"
cur.execute(QUERY)
myresult = cur.fetchall()

def Array():
    array= []
    for x in myresult:
        y = str(x[0])
        array.append(y)
    return array

Action = Array()

def main():
    while True:

        if ((Action[0]=='1' and Action[1]=='0') or (Action[0]=='0' and Action[1]=='1')):
             QUERY= "SELECT `Time` FROM `test` WHERE `Street`='StreetRight' "
             cur.execute(QUERY)
             myresult = cur.fetchall()
             t=Array()
             time=t[0]
             TurnOnGreenHorizental(int(time))


        elif ((Action[2]=='1' and Action[3]=='0') or (Action[2]=='0' and Action[3]=='1')):
             QUERY= "SELECT `Time` FROM `test` WHERE `Street`='StreetUp' "
              cur.execute(QUERY)
            myresult = cur.fetchall()
             t=Array()
             time=t[0]
             print(time)
             TurnOnGreenVertical(int(time))
db.commit()
GPIO.add_event_detect(PushButton, GPIO.FALLING,callback=my_callback,bouncetime=12000)

main()
```

Comment: "the "main" and "my_callback" are executing together !!". Yes, that's how it works. The callback is spawned in a separate thread and will run in parallel to your main code.

Comment: @larsks How can I pause the main for a little time and release it when finishing "my_callback"  function ?

Comment: I suggest doing some reading about [thread synchronization](https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732?gi=bb709a0bc24b).